# Coding HTML email for gmail. Linked image shows neon blue background

Tags: html, email, gmail, html-email

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. I have tried everything I know and read all the articles I could find. Nothing has worked

Basically, there is what seems to be a neon blue background color showing up ONLY on Gmail in the `<td>` containing the header image.

Screenshot (with image missing):

[image]

Screenshot (with image showing neon background):

[image]

Table code:

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="body-wrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="max-width: 600px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" class="container" bgcolor="=FFFFFF" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; line-height:10px; font-size:6px">
        <div class="container1">
          <a href="http://www.rolla.com" style="text-decoration: none; border: none"><img src="https://rolla.igamingcloud.com/Images/Emails/MailSystem/Upload/rolla_system_header.gif" align=“absbottom” width="100%" style="display:block; max-height: 172px; max-width: 600px; border:none; padding: 0px; margin 0px" border="0" alt="Rolla Casino Logo"
            /></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have specified background colour `white` in the table and td.  I have also added style attributes to the border to the `href` and `img` tags. None of these have worked.

The classes `container` and `container1` both contain:

```
border-width:0 none;
background: #ffffff;
text-decoration: none;
text-decoration-color: #ffffff;
```

Even when I unlinked the header image and sent another test, the blue was there!

Comment: did the answer below work for you?

Comment: Thanks Syfer. There was the error you point out and also a missing ":" on a margin attribute. Those 2 fixes worked. Thanks!

Comment: Please select it as the correct answer if it solved the issue you had in your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you added an equal rather than a hash in background color decoration for the td. You have `bgcolor="=FFFFFF"` instead of `bgcolor="#FFFFFF"`. Below is the fixed code:

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" class="body-wrap" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="max-width: 600px">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" class="container" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; line-height:10px; font-size:6px">
        <div class="container1">
          <a href="http://www.rolla.com" style="text-decoration: none; border: none"><img src="https://rolla.igamingcloud.com/Images/Emails/MailSystem/Upload/rolla_system_header.gif" align=“absbottom” width="100%" style="display:block; max-height: 172px; max-width: 600px; border:none; padding: 0px; margin 0px" border="0" alt="Rolla Casino Logo"
            /></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Cheers